# How to mock model when testing setupController or private Route methods

Tags: unit-testing, testing, ember.js, ember-data

When I try to mock `model` by writing `let mockModel = this.owner.lookup('model:realModel');` in my route (unit) test, I receive the error 
`Error: You should not call 'create' on a model. Instead, call 'store.createRecord' with the attributes you would like to set.`

What's the proper way to mock `model` to test processing within `setupController` and other private route methods?

Code to illustrate testing setupController/private route methods:

**app\routes\application.js**

```
export default Route.extend({

  _postModelProcessing(inputModel){
      ....
      return processedModelData;
  },

  setupController(controller, model){

  let processedModelData = _postModelProcessing(model);   

  }

})
```

***tests\unit\routes\application-test.js***

```
module('Unit | Route | application', function(hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);
  ...      
  test('private _postModelProcessing correctly processes model data', function(assert) {
    let route = this.owner.lookup('route:application');

    // This line throws the Error mentioned above
    let mockModel = this.owner.lookup('model:realModel');

  // what I hoped to do, if the above line didn't throw an error:
  let mockModelData = [
    mockModel.create({
      category: 'Leopard',
      childCategories: [],
      parentCategory: null
    }),
    mockModel.create({
      category: 'Snow Leopard',
      childCategories: [], 
      parentCategory: 'Leopard'
    }),
    mockModel.create({
      category: 'Persian Leopard',
      childCategories: [],
      parentCategory: 'Leopard'
    })
  ]

  let processedData = route._postModelProcessing(mockModelData);
  let leopardFirstChild = processedData[0].get('childCategories')[0];

  assert.equal(leopardFirstChild.get('category'), 'Snow Leopard');

  })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what the error message says, use `store.createRecord`:

```
module('Unit | Route | application', function(hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);
  ...      
  test('private _postModelProcessing correctly processes model data', function(assert) {
    let route = this.owner.lookup('route:application');
    let store = this.owner.lookup('service:store');

  // what I hoped to do, if the above line didn't throw an error:
  let mockModelData = [
    store.createRecord('real-model', {
      category: 'Leopard',
      childCategories: [],
      parentCategory: null
    }),
    store.createRecord('real-model', {
      category: 'Snow Leopard',
      childCategories: [], 
      parentCategory: 'Leopard'
    }),
    store.createRecord('real-model', {
      category: 'Persian Leopard',
      childCategories: [],
      parentCategory: 'Leopard'
    })
  ]

  let processedData = route._postModelProcessing(mockModelData);
  let leopardFirstChild = processedData[0].get('childCategories')[0];

  assert.equal(leopardFirstChild.get('category'), 'Snow Leopard');

  })

});
```

Comment: I was originally trying to `route.store.createRecord(...).save()` and then `route.store.findAll(...).then()` in order to simulate acquiring a RecordArrayManager, which I think (but am not sure) simulates an object like the actual `model`, but somehow that didn't work. I landed on this solution too, but it seems odd we have to manually construct our own array. Why is `store.createRecord()` any different than `mockModel.create()` if we aren't further interacting with the DataStore?

Comment: It has to do with ember data internals; things like isNew and isLoaded.